# Email all test case logs to my email using Detox e2e testing library from bitbar.com device farming service

Tags: linux, react-native, detox, testdroid

I am testing react native app on bitbar.com device farm and using Detox/wix e2e testing library. I want to get the test case pass/fail logs to my email from several devices which I select on bitbar.com device farm.

Is there any feature in Detox library to configure email ?

bitbar.com is actually using loggly.com logging services to send logs to email, but there is no guide to set it up in react-native application. Need help.

Comment: can you help me for setting up bitbar for detox as their documentation is not good

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there is no option to send e-mails from Detox.

> Make each program do one thing well. To do a new job, build afresh rather than complicate old programs by adding new "features".

Most likely, you'll need to write a script to archive detox artifacts and send the archive to your e-mail account.

This is a question out of scope of Detox. But you can take a look at this file as a reference:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wix/detox/master/scripts/upload_artifact.sh

It archives artifacts after a test run and uploads them to S3.

You can develop a similar solution for yourself. Good luck!